# How do I design a specific super class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I am trying to refactor a solution to bring on board another project.
I have a Core project where common classes across projects reside.

I've tried to simpify my question by using 2 imaginary projects: Holidays and Weather...

I have a file load process setup for the Holidays project which has the following 2 classes:

```
public class Job
{
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Security Security { get; set; }

    protected IList<File> _files = new List<File>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<File> Files
    {
        get { return _files; }
    }
}

public class File
{
    public virtual string FileName { get; set; }
    public virtual FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public virtual FileStatusType FileStatusType { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

The file load process for the Weather project has exactly the same structure as Holidays, except that the Jobs class does not have a Security property.

My question is, is it possible to somehow move both classes into the Core project to allow both projects to use them?
Obviously Weather does not need the Security property, so I was thinking I would have a Core.Job class without Security, and then extend the Core.Job in Holidays.Job.

But once I do that, in the Core.File class, what Job is it referring to? As it sits in the Core project it must be the Core.Job.
So would I then need to have Job and File sit in Holidays, and Weather (and any other future projects) use the Core.Job and Core.File?

I don't want the Core project to have any references to sub projects.

I am using NHibernate, and so have mapping files - adding to the complexity.

Hope this is clear enough

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear why confuse on the soluton offered by you (assuming that I right understood you)

```
//Core DLL 

public class Job
{
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }  
    protected IList<File> _files = new List<File>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<File> Files
    {
        get { return _files; }
    }
}
```

in the **Hollidays** you have

```
public class HollidayJob : Job
{
    public virtual Security Security { get; set; }
}
```

in **Weather** simply use a type `Job`, if it selfsufficient.

In this case you refer `CoreDLL` from `Holliday` project and `Weather`. When you serialize it via `NHibernate` it for `HollidayJob`  save one field more, but when `Weather` reads the same table it skips that field, as don't know anything, and don't actually care abotu it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Tigran. But what would the File class look like please? As in my code example above the file class has a Job property on it. So, would I then need a HolidayFile that contains a HolidayJob?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do this, but I am not sure whether it brings you true benefit:

- Does the Core itself work with the base `Job` in any way? If it does not, implementing `Job` separately in each project may help you keep coupling loose, even though I'd a little redundant. In code I wrote, I have sometimes introduced unnecessary dependencies by extracting interfaces without adding true benefit. This is why I am a bit precautious.
- In case Core does acutal work with it, the part to refactor into the common base `Job` is perhaps the interface it works with.
- You may think of an interface instead of a base class. `Security` may semantically belong to another interface. Moreover, you hand over a lot of control over your classes to the `Core`.
- Do you ever hand a job from one project to another (or are they mapped to the same DB table via NHibernate?)? If you don't, an internal redundant class may be fine too.

Comment: Thanks Mudu. In answer to your questions: Core does not work with the base Job. A Job will not be passed from one project to another. Could you add some code explaining the redundant interface idea you mention above please? I followed a pattern described by Tigran below, so HolidayJob and then in the File class had IJob that was interface by Core.Job. However, this resulted in the following nHibernate error: An association from the table FL_File refers to an unmapped class: Core.FileLoad.IJob. Thanks

Comment: I did not expressed too clearly. Before I edited the first point: "Redundant" just meant two separate `Job` implementation, nothing fancy. Unfortunately I don't know NHibernate too well.